# Как выровнять по вертикали меню сайта

Tags: css

```css
* {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}
.header {
 background-color: #f6f2f2;
 overflow: hidden;

}
.margin160 {
 margin: 10px 160px;
}
.menu {
 background-color: #313030;
 
 height: 90px;
}
.menu ul {
 margin: 0;
 margin-left: 360px;
 
}
.menu ul li {
 list-style-type: none;
 display: inline
 font-size: 14px;
 
 
}
.menu a {
 color: #d7d7d7;
 text-decoration: none;
 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="header">
   <div class="margin160">
    <div class="menu">
    
     <ul>

      <a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
      <a href="#">About me</a></li>
     </ul>
   
    </div>
    <div class="float-left">
     <h1>Our strong organisation</h1>
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam sed sapien turpis.
      Duis finibus, purus vehicula efficitur imperdiet, turpis tellus rhoncus dui, finibus rutrum purus elit at leo.
      Nunc elit lacus, mollis sit amet suscipit sed, egestas nec metus. Praesent sit amet ultricies eros.
      Cras erat ipsum, cursus id lectus quis, accumsan placerat turpis. Donec luctus mattis quam quis sagittis.
      Nam ut lectus mauris. Curabitur porttitor congue metus vitae fringilla. Maecenas sapien arcu, venenatis eget libero ac, finibus dapibus quam.
     </p>
     <button>Contact Us</button>
    </div>
    <video width="400" height="300" controls="controls">
     <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4">
    </video>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

пробывал vertical-align не получается так

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Всего лишь добавьте `line-height: 90px;` для `menu ul li`

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.header {
  background-color: #f6f2f2;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.margin160 {
  margin: 10px 160px;
}

.menu {
  background-color: #313030;
  height: 90px;
}

.menu ul {
  margin: 0;
  margin-left: 360px;
}

.menu ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 90px;
}

.menu a {
  color: #d7d7d7;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="margin160">
    <div class="menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About me</a></li>
      </ul>

    </div>
    <div class="float-left">
      <h1>Our strong organisation</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam sed sapien turpis. Duis finibus, purus vehicula efficitur imperdiet, turpis tellus rhoncus dui, finibus rutrum purus elit at leo. Nunc elit lacus, mollis sit amet suscipit sed, egestas
        nec metus. Praesent sit amet ultricies eros. Cras erat ipsum, cursus id lectus quis, accumsan placerat turpis. Donec luctus mattis quam quis sagittis. Nam ut lectus mauris. Curabitur porttitor congue metus vitae fringilla. Maecenas sapien arcu,
        venenatis eget libero ac, finibus dapibus quam.
      </p>
      <button>Contact Us</button>
    </div>
    <video width="400" height="300" controls="controls">
     <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4">
    </video>
  </div>
</div>
```

P.S.: в Вашем коде в `.menu ul` у Вас не достает открывающих`<li>`